# List, where \ref{...} have been made

Tags: cross-referencing

I want a document where I have different sections, and each section has many references to other sections, like

```
\section{a}
\label{a}
See \nameref{b}

\section{b}
\label{b}
See \nameref{a}

\section{c}
\label{c}
See \nameref{a}
```

Is it possible to createa a function, or maybe there's already a module for it which I didn't find, to make something like

```
\section{b}
\label{b}
See \nameref{a}
\printrefs
```

Resulting in something like:

**a**

See b

A has been referenced on in *a* (page n) and *c* (page m)

**b**

b has been referenced on in *a* (page suchandsuch)

See a

**c**

See a

... or some thing similiar.

Comment: see `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mmxref` package for this (yes, it was written for this answer). Thanks to egreg who [kindly provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484806/73317) a good starting point for the code.

Download `mmxref.sty` from [here](https://github.com/frougon/TeX-stuff/tree/master/LaTeX/mmxref)<sup>1</sup> and put it in the same directory as your document, or somewhere in your `TEXINPUTS` (in the latter case, you may have to refresh a database of available files for TeX: this is the usual routine for manually-installed packages). The [mmxref package page](https://github.com/frougon/TeX-stuff/tree/master/LaTeX/mmxref) contains further usage instructions.

Your document can then look like this (let's call it `docu.tex`). Note that in general, two compilations are necessary to have everything in order (as usual with references that go through the `.aux` file; the `mmxref` package warns you if more compilations are needed).

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mmxref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

% The default prefix for labels created by mmxref is “mmxref-”. You can easily
% change this prefix:
%\mmxSetLabelPrefix{prefix of your choice (possibly empty)}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.2pt}

\part{A Great Part}
\mmxlabel{a great part}

Foo bar in the part. All that.

\mmxInsertBackReferences[\emph{This fascinating part was referenced}]{a great
  part}

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\mmxlabel{first chapter}

See~\mmxautoref{another section}, \mmxautoref{section in 2nd chapter},
and~\mmxautoref{a subsection}.

\mmxInsertBackReferences{first chapter}

\section{A Section}
\mmxlabel{a section}

% If the preceding \mmxlabel were to be omitted, the backreference generated
% by the following \mmxautoref command would point to the last \mmxlabel
% issued, which corresponds to the first chapter.
Some text. See~\mmxautoref{a great part}.

\section{Another Section}
\mmxlabel{another section}

See~\mmxautoref{first chapter}.

\mmxInsertBackReferences{another section}

\subsection{A Subsection}
\mmxlabel{a subsection}
See~\mmxautoref{another section}, \mmxautoref{a subsection},
and~\mmxautoref{first chapter}.

%\mmxInsertBackReferences[This marvelous place]{a subsection}
\mmxInsertBackReferences{a subsection}

\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\mmxlabel{second chapter}

\mmxInsertBackReferences{second chapter}

\section{A Section In The Second Chapter}
\mmxlabel{section in 2nd chapter} See~\mmxautoref{a subsection},
\mmxautoref{another section} and also \mmxautoref{third chapter}, which starts
on page~\mmxpageref{third chapter}.

\mmxInsertBackReferences{section in 2nd chapter}

\chapter{The Third Chapter}
\mmxlabel{third chapter}

Text in the third chapter.

\section{And Now For Something Completely Different}
\mmxlabel{Something Completely Different}

Let's point to \mmxautoref[third chapter]{second chapter}, but in way that
makes the back-reference be \mmxautoref{third chapter} instead of
\mmxautoref{Something Completely Different}. That's what the optional argument
of \verb|\mmxref| and \verb|\mmxautoref| is for.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can redefine the following commands to change the wording (possibly the language) of inserted phrases. For instance, you can get `\mmxref` to speak French by adding this between `\usepackage{mmxref}` and `\begin{document}`:

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}           % only necessary if you use it for customization
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxSeparatorBetweenTwo { }
  { ~et~ }

\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxSeparatorBetweenMoreThanTwo { }
  { ,~ }

\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxSeparatorBetweenFinalTwo { }
  { ~et~ }

\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxFormatSimpleRef { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { part } { partie }
        { chapter } { chapitre }
        { section } { section }
        { subsection } { section } % intentional: “subsection” is too ugly here
        { subsubsection } { section } % ditto
        { paragraph } { paragraphe }
        { subparagraph } { paragraphe } % ditto
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { mmxref } { main/undefined-ref-format-for-counter } {#1}
      }
  }

\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxFormatStartOfInsertionPhrase { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { part } { Cette~partie~a~été~référencée }
        { chapter } { Ce~chapitre~a~été~référencé }
        { section } { Cette~section~a~été~référencée }
        % Intentional: “subsection” is too ugly here
        { subsection } { Cette~section~a~été~référencée }
        { subsubsection } { Cette~section~a~été~référencée } % ditto
        { paragraph } { Ce~paragraphe~a~été~référencé }
        { subparagraph } { Ce~paragraphe~a~été~référencé } % ditto
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { mmxref } { main/undefined-ref-format-for-counter } {#1}
      }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl

\RenewDocumentCommand \mmxFormatBackRef { m m m m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
      { \mmxref_insert_ref:nn {#4} {#2} }

    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { part }
        { à~la~partie \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        { chapter }
        { au~chapitre \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        { section }
        { à~la~section \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        % Intentional: “subsection” is too ugly here
        { subsection }
        { à~la~section \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        % Ditto
        { subsubsection }
        { à~la~section \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        { paragraph }
        { au~paragraphe \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
        % Ditto
        { subparagraph }
        { au~paragraphe \nobreakspace \l__myprefix_mmxFormatBackRef_ref_tl
          \c_space_tl page \nobreakspace #3 }
      }
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { mmxref } { main/undefined-ref-format-for-counter } {#1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here is what this would do to page 3 of the previous `docu.tex` file (the bits that remain in English were entered *as is* in `docu.tex`, this is just an example!):

[image]

---

**Footnote**

1. If you don't know how to download `mmxref.sty`, click on the `mmxref.sty` file name on the [mmxref package page](https://github.com/frougon/TeX-stuff/tree/master/LaTeX/mmxref), then on the *Raw* button and use some menu item like *File → Save* in your web browser. (Another way is to clone the Git repository, but you need [Git](https://git-scm.com/) for that.)